# R: quick way to fit `lm` to each row or column and then do `ncvTest`

Tags: r, linear-regression

I used `apply` to fit a linear model (`lm`) to each column, but it's very time-consuming, probably because I have 626374 columns in `MyValues`. The code I used are:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores = 10)
lmFitGA.list <- base::apply(MyValues[,1:626374], 2, FUN = 
function(x){lm(x ~ MyValues$Gestational.Age)})
```

I also tried to use:

`lmFitGA <- lm(as.matrix(MyValues[,1:626374]) ~ MyValues$Gestational.Age)`

without using `apply`, which was very quick. However, `lmFitGA` object is `lm` fitted by column and I don't know how to use `lmFitGA` for the following `ncvTest`.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't see a coherent statistical plan behind this. Half a million y-outcomes versus one x-predictor? What kind of data are you analyzing that would support such an effort? The `apply` function is surely _not_ what you want if you are attempting parallelism. And what is `ncvTest`?

Comment: `lapply` will loop over your columns faster than `apply`. You just have to drop the `MARGIN=2` argument you've got.

Comment: @42- I want to fit a linear model to each probe(column), so the formula for each probe is: probe intensity of each sample ~ gestational age. ncvTest is to test heteroscedasticity.

Comment: @Brian, thank you, I will have a try.

Comment: There are more principled statistical approaches to this type of problem. Telling you how to do this flawed procedure would be committing statistical malpractice. For one thing the notion that expression of proteins or RNA's would be linear on a time scale seem exceeding unlikely from an embryologic viewpoint. You should seek expert statistical advice.

Comment: @42-, thank you, I just did this for comparing different models, I want to find a quicker way to get the fit list. Thank you very much for your advice, very useful!!

Comment: Using a matrix on the LHS is how you should fit this. Otherwise `lm` needs to do *a lot* of redundant work. However, `car::ncvTest` doesn't support `mlm` objects. Fitting the models independently in a loop must be slow and using `ncvTest` on these models afterwards will be even slower because it actually *refits* the models. But testing that many models for heterogeneity of residuals is nonsense anyway.

Comment: @Roland, thank you so much, you are right, probably I only need to subset 100 columns as an example to have a look.